# Pyspark installationError: No module named 'pyspark'

Tags: python, pyspark

I am looking to install pyspark module without using pip.
I have completed all installation steps, still I am getting No module named 'pyspark'.

I have downloaded apache spark from https://spark.apache.org

I also followed:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iarn1KHeouc&list=PLot-YkcC7wZ_2sxmRTZr2c121rjcaleqv&index=3
- https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c

[Here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj5Ps.png)

Comment: in the error image, I don't see any error. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://medium.com/big-data-engineering/how-to-install-apache-spark-2-x-in-your-pc-e2047246ffc3. It works on Windows platforms and is also compatible with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Please avoid link only answers as the target site can become unreachable in the future. Quote the part that answers the question as stated in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).